# Excel cell as a user input and as a formula

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to make cell E23 as a user input and as a formula cell if user does not enter any value. For eg: If user enters a value in cell E23, then consider that value. If user does not enter any value then copy value from cell B23. Below is the vba code which I tried.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$23" And Target.Value = "" Then
     Target.Formula = "=B23"
End If
```

The code works fine until I change the value in cell B23 by a selection made in the dropdown combobox. When I change the selection in combobox from option 1 to option 2, new value gets updated in cell B23 which must be copied into E23. But it gives me a runtime error '13' Type mismatch.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you click debug and let me know where the error highlight?

Comment: Try to nest second i.e. condition after `AND` inside first one. `If Target.Address = "$E$23" Then` and also put `Application.EnableEvents = False/True` switch before `If Loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that this line

```
Target.Formula = "=B23"
```

changes the target cell, and that triggers a `Worksheet_Change` event that changes the target cell, and that triggers a `Worksheet_Change` event … and so on.

So you need to disable the events before you change the target cell (and re-enable them afterwards).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$23" And Target.Value = vbNullString Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Formula = "=B23"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Alternative that works also when multiple cells are selected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E23")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Range("E23").Value = vbNullString Then
            Range("E23").Formula = "=B23"
        Else
            Range("E23").Value = Range("E23").Value - Range("E17").Value
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above code but it is still giving the same error when I change a selection in combobox dropdown - which changes the value of cell B23.

Comment: @PEH : I am getting runtime error '13' Type mismatch error in below line:
If Target.Address = "$E$23" And Target.Value = "" Then

Comment: @Abhi See my edit. This issue happens when more than one cell is selected when the change event runs. Therefore we need to intersect the target range with the cell E23 and only check the value of E23 and change the formula only in E23 instead of the whole target range.

Comment: @PEH : The alternative code is working perfectly fine. Thank you!
In addition to the above criteria, there is another criteria I need to satisfy: If user enter a value in cell E23, then subtract the rebate (coming from cell E17) from cell E23.

Comment: @Abhi I recommend not to do this. This would confuse every user if he enters eg `20` as value and then it suddenly becomes `18` because something gets magically subtracted and he doesn't know why. This is a very uncommon behavior! Therefore it is better to have a cell for input the real value and subtract the rebate in another cell. If this answer solves your original question please mark it as solution.

Comment: @PEH: I support your recommendation. But the user requirement is such that if E23 has no value then pull the value from B23. If E23 has a user input value then deduct the rebate (coming from E17) from it. So it wont confuse the users since they already know the expected output. Is there a way I can insert both the conditions in VBA?

Comment: @PEH: Thank you PEH! This is great.